# Stopping apk file real devices

Tags: javascript

I have a android project in Eclipse. It's working fine in emulator if i click emulator options 'Use Host Gpu'. Logcat has no error showing. Export the apk file, it's running but five seconds later stopping. I exported the apk file with **file->export->android->export android application**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

How can i fix it? Is not showing really problem use 'use host gpu'?

Comment: What does it have to do with javascript ?

Comment: So no error on device logs either?

Comment: I have no error logs with host gpu. If i not click 'use host gpu' for working,have so many error. it confuses my head.

Comment: I made a game with cocos2dx, and im using java ,c++